# How to properly start a detached React Native app

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am using React Native for the first time and I can see that we can detach from the Expo. I have no reason to detach, but I am sure will have later so I will detach from the start.

Question: What is the commands to start directly detached app using react native commands.

I have used **create-react-native-app my-app** then run **expo detach** this seemed to detach the app but for some reason only android folder is showing while ios folder is missing, anyone have any idea how do I have both platforms created on a detached version!

Thanks

Comment: Are you developing on macOS?

Comment: no, its windows, does it make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A Mac is required to build projects with native code for iOS. You can follow the Quick Start to learn how to build your app using Create React Native App instead.

As per the `react-native` docs, you can't detach & develop for iOS unless you are on a Mac. [Link(Under Building Projects with Native Code)](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: I can get a mac its not a problem, but the question is why the ios folder is missing when I run exp detach?

Comment: Because you need a Mac to develop for iOS. Try to download Xcode or run an Xcode project on Windows.

Comment: so u saying u have to be on a mac computer when u run exp detach, in order to get the ios folder?

Comment: npm run eject, brought me the ios folder